# UITabBar doesn't change the color of its background

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

Easy code

```
class PreferencesTabBar: UITabBar {

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawRect(rect)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 166.0/255.0, green: 142.0/255.0, blue: 83.0/255.0, alpha: 0.5)
    }

}
```

I set the class of the UITabBar in IB to my custom class, but the background doesn't become the color that I wanted, but instead it becomes completely transparent, it's like there is no UITabBar at all (of course excepts the UITabBarItems I can still see them)

Comment: did you manage to solve the problem? If so, please close the question by adding your own answer and accepting it, or by accepting the existing answer. Otherwise, give feedback and additional details to see if anyone else moght be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to set the background of your tab bar from the view controller that holds your tab bar, by creating a `@IBOutlet` (ctrl-drag) from the tab bar.

```
// ViewController.swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTabBar: UITabBar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        myTabBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 166.0/255.0, green: 142.0/255.0, blue: 83.0/255.0, alpha: 0.5)
    }

    // ...

}
```